# razor dynamic name of the class

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
<span class="abc">abc</span>
```

I want to have @postid as well in there so that the name of the class is generated as abc123. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<span class="abc@(postid)">abc</span>
```